# How to send and store dates for different timezones between NodeJS and MySQL?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I've researched this for a while and haven't found an actual solution.

I have an App that runs react and connects to an express backend. The App has locations all over the world which can be booked over a time span, and also locations can be disabled for a time span.

Now these locations are in their own time zone, of course, and I'm wondering how to save my dates in the DB? Should I store everything as DATETIME and store in UTC timezone? Should I store DATETIME of local timezone and use another column for timezone? Should I use TIMESTAMPs and store in server timezone?

Axios runs a toISOString if you try to send a date object, so unless I convert it to a string that keeps timezone information, timestamps won't make much sense.

Also, how do I send it back to the user and reflect their own time zone? Do I use `dateStrings: true` and convert the time on the server? On the client? Do I let mysql do the work?

There must be a practical solution that doesn't involve converting back and forth between strings. The solutions I found are not practical (i.e. dont work with mysql2) or don't really solve any problem, because we're still typing back and forth. What are the best practises for handling dates.

If someone can point in the right direction I would appreciate it!

Comment: see if this helps you https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/366744

Comment: @nbk going full UTC seems to be the most straight forward way. But I have full day bookings that go from 1 am to 11 pm. If someone in the US books, that time will shift to the next day. So I'm doing a lot of converting and calculating with times/dates. That's why I almost want to store local times along with their timezone offset directly. But that on the other hand seems really messy. You can't tell the timezone for any time. This seems to be our seniors plan though. So how would I convince them to do it another way? :s